# Need help figuring Definite Integral Formulas

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I took a scan but it isit really clear what the forumlas are, could someone help me fill up the upper & lower bound?

[image]

**UPDATE**

3 has an error ...

[image]

Comment: The third item has no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting lower bound by l.b. and upper bound by u.b.:

1) l.b.= b ; u.b.= a

2) l.b.= a ; u.b.= b

3) l.b.= b ; u.b.= a

4) l.b.= a ; u.b.= b

5) l.b.= -a; u.b.= a

6) l.b.= -a; u.b.= a

Comment: If the second integral in 3) is $\int_c^b f(x)\,dx$, I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Actually, can someone edit 3) with hypothesis that the lower bound of the second term in LHS is c? I can't think of what the limits should be. This is a little embarrassing.

Comment: Oh I looked at the book errata and 3 has an error ... it should be upper bound of 3 term shld be b instead of c http://i.imgur.com/GwK6r.png